# Creating News Feeds

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

How would you create a news feed such as something facebook has implemented or even LinkedIn? Is there a Generic table in the database Such as:

```
------------------
|     Feed       |
------------------
|  int Id        |
|  string type   |
|  string refId  |
|  string text   |
|  Date date     |
------------------
```

Where the `refId` would be the reference the the key item in another table and type would be something like `Upload,Delete,Post Comment, etc` and you would have to add a new Feed item to the database for whatever you want to be in the feed. Like if you uploaded multiple documents, you would do `refId = "101,203,303"` which references another tables keys. Any reading material which gives me an idea of this would be appreciated or even a good solution for small/medium websites.

Comment: I recommend using [**HTML 5 WebSockets**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/), which are mainly used for real-time news feed and social media updates. Another technique is to use Ruby on Rails (+ ActiveRecord) and I found out that [**Cramp**](http://cramp.in/) is a dedicated library for that type of technique.

Comment: @Socialz The biggest problem I have is Database Structure. What would be a good method to structure something like a feed.

Comment: I would just simply remove everything except the `id` and store all feed activity in a JSON in `refs`, for instance. I made a small preview of what it would look like to use a JSON, now if the JSON was changing constantly with HTML 5 WebSockets or so, it would be a live feed. [**Preview the demonstration >**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/0c9-kv3)

Comment: @Socialz I understand what you did and that would seem like a solution, however, would it be practical? If the data is always changing and you don't have something set in stone, then wouldn't it be hard to maintain? Also you want to efficiently find the right data instead of reading from every row and finding where the `UserId==1` and if it's a `Upload`. That would be hard to do with just a `REF`. You could fall back on creating columns for the essentials such as `USERID` however that would leave you the problem of searching for relevant information. The time complexity would be pretty bad.

Comment: That is where [**NoSQL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) steps in. Even _StackOverflow_ uses NoSQL and it works well with such data flow with no downtime, most of the time :-)

Comment: @Socialz So basically, it's a separate database which uses document data to store items. If I'm getting this right, I should use my regular MSSQL database for the regular tables such as storing `users,likes,etc` and use the NOSQL for doing computations that are heavy such as `searching and storing activity streams`. I've been looking at `Redis/RavenDB` and `RavenDB` seems easier to implement and query but `Redis` is a whole lot faster. I wish there was some better documentation on `Redis` for beginners.